# How Do We Wire Up Converted Unit Tests in Doppl?

Tags: doppl

I am attempting to replicate what I see in `PartyClickerSample` in a fresh project, and am having difficulty with the pod and using it from Swift to set up the unit tests.

Based on `PartyClickerSample`, AFAICT, what I am supposed to do is put a `Podfile` like this in the `iosTest/` directory (that contains a newly-created Xcode project):

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'iosTest' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'testdoppllib', :path => '../app/build'
end
```

Then:

- In `AppDelegate.swift`, import `testdoppllib` and call `DopplRuntime.start()` from the `application()` func
- In `ViewController.swift`, import `testdoppllib` and call `runResource()` on... something that I can't quite figure out what it maps to

However, I can't even get to the latter bullet, as things start going sideways from the outset.

`pod install` seems to work as expected:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `testdoppllib` from `../app/build`
Downloading dependencies
Installing testdoppllib (0.1.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `iosTest.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total pod installed.
```

However, when I re-open the workspace:

- In the Xcode tree thingy, Pods/Products/ shows `testdoppillib.framework` in red (which doesn't look good) and also shows `Pods_iosTest.framework` in black

[image: Xcode Pods/Products/ Screenshot]

- If I try `import testdoppillib`, I get a message saying that Xcode does not recognize that name
- If I try `import Pods_iosTest`, Xcode seems to find it, but then it does not recognize `DopplRuntime.start()`

So, what are the steps, in a Cocoapods-based Doppl setup, for starting the Doppl-created unit tests in Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running pod install with set up the testdoppllib framework, but doesn't actually build it. One of the frustrating parts of the cocoapods process is you'll need to run build in Xcode, which should first build testdoppllib, then your Swift code.

To summarize, testdoppllib shows up as red, but it's most likely OK and just needs to be built. Once it's build, your Swift code should see "import testdoppllib"

For runResource, that's a little more complicated.

The Doppl gradle plugin writes a file called dopplTests.txt to the build/j2objcSrcGenTest directory. That's a listing of all the test classes. You need to add that file to Xcode, then pass in that name to DopplJunitTestHelper.runResource.

There's probably a way to set that up with cocoapods, but we haven't done that yet.

[image: Adding dopplTests.txt to Xcode]

Comment: OK, building the project cleared up the `testdoppllib` issue. But there's no `DopplJunitTestHelper` class in the app. I have `testDoppl "co.doppl.lib:androidbasetest:0.8.5.0"` in the `dopplConfig`, but none of those classes seem to be available. How does the `Podfile` for an `iosTest`-style app know to pull in `testDoppl` dependencies?

Comment: The class seems to be `CoTouchlabDopplTestingDopplJunitTestHelper`. I can now run the tests, but I'm crashing, because the test helper can't find my test class. I'll file a separate question for that.